# Is it possible to generate a test class using Gradle?

Tags: java, testing, gradle

Gradle provides a default `App.java` java source file and its test class at the time of creation of project.

I created java class under main:

```
/src/main/java/some/package/algo/Sort.java
```

I would like to create a test class that corresponds to it.

```
/test/main/java/some/package/algo/SortTest.java
```

I can do that manually but is it possible that Gradle or any gradle command does it for me whenever I create a new regular Java Source file.

I am not using IDE and IDE provide such options.

Similarly any gradle command, If I have a test file than Gradle create java source file under main source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task createTestForSource {
    inputs.dir 'src/main/java'
    outputs.dir 'src/test/java'

    doLast {
        fileTree('src/main/java').visit { FileVisitDetails fvd ->
            if (!fvd.directory) {
                String sourcePath = fvd.relativePath.asPath
                String testPath = sourcePath.replace('.java', 'Test.java')
                File testFile = file("src/test/java/$testPath")
                if (!testFile.exists()) {
                    testFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
                    testFile.text = // do your magic here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```